Prove $f$ does not attain its minimum

Let $C[0,1]$ be a family of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with
$||x||_{\infty}=\sup\limits_{t\in [0,1]}|x(t)|$. Define $$A=\{x\in
 C[0,1]: x(1)=1, -1\leq x(t)\leq 1\}.$$
$a)$ Prove $f:C[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}x^2(t)dt$ continuous
on $A$. Is $f$ uniformly continuous on $A$?
$b)$ Prove that $f$ does not attain minimum on $A$. Is $A$ compact?

I already done part a), where I showed that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$.
I also done half of b), in which I showed $A$ is not compact by giving a counterexample of the sequence $\{t^n\}$ having no convergent subsequence. I'm stuck at proving $f$ does not attains its minimum on $A$. 
Could someone help me with this part? Thanks in advance!

“I also done half of c)” – what is c) ?

I edited, thanks for checking

Let $x_n(t)=0$ for $t \le 1-\frac  1n$ and $x_n(t)=n(t-1+\frac 1 n)$ for $1-\frac  1n< t \le 1$.  Then $\int_0^{1} x_n^{2}(t)dt$ tends to $0$ so the infimum is $0$. But $f(x)=0$ would make $x(t)=0$ for all $t$ violating the condition $x(1)=1$.

Obviously, $f(x)\geq0$ for every function $x$.
To prove that $0$ is the infimum, take functions defined as $g_n(x)=0$ if $x\in[0,1-1/n]$ and $g_n(x)=n(x-1+1/n)$ (i.e the graph of $g_n$ is a triangle with base the segment $[1-1/n,1]$ and height $1$).
The integrals of $g_n^2$ clearly tend to $0$ as they are bounded by $1$ but their support is as small as desired.
Nonetheless, there is no function $g$ in $A$ such that the integral of $g^2$ is $0$, as we must have that $g^2$ is continuous and $g^2(1)=1$. Thus, $g^2$ is bigger than $1/2$ in some neighbourhood $(1-\epsilon,1)$ and its integral in the whole interval $[0,1]$, being a non-negative function, will be strictly bigger than $\epsilon/2$.
This in turn implies, in an alternative way, that $A$ cannot be compact, as $f$ is continuous and thus should attain its minimum it that was the case.

If you consider functions of the form
$$
x_n(t)=\begin{cases}
0, & 0\leq t\leq 1 - \frac 1n\\
nt-n+1, & 1 - \frac 1n < t \leq 1
\end{cases},
$$
for which $f(x) = \frac{1}{3n}$, you see that $f$ can take values that are arbitrarily close to zero, while you clearly have that $f \ge 0$. You just need to show that zero is not attainable in $A$. In fact, the only continuous function for which $f$ vanishes is the zero function, that does not belong to $A$.

I think you mistook the condition $x(1)=1$ for $x(0)=1$.

@geetha290krm I did! Fixed it now.
